# opponent moves promise in multiplayer game

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, multiplayer, yield-keyword

I have spent the last four days studying promises, coroutines, fibers, continuations, etc.

I am still unable to see how to resolve my multiplayer turn-based card game moves, in which the starting player is effectively the game 'controller' of up to five, either AI or human players.

The code below works but has one problem:-

it cannot detect human oppo's card moves and therefore continues playing without them, which, of course makes a mess.

Can anyone please suggest either a change to my overall concept or a way to use promise or one of any other 'synchronising' constructs?

Here are the four key areas of my code:

```
function oppoPlays () {
    // can only go through here if game starter
    if (joiner!="") {return;}
    for (pp=1; pp<numberofplayers; pp++) {
        if (oppoType[pp] == "AI") {
            // an AI player moves
            .
            .
        } else {
            // non-AI player
            var yourTurnmsg="It's "+playerNames[pp]+"'s turn";
            // tell human player that it's their turn
            $("#text_message").val(yourTurnmsg).trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { keyCode: 13, which: 13 }));
            // how to detect human oppo's card moved?

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
// chat functionality
$("#text_message").on("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13){
        payload = new Object();
        payload.action = 'chat_text';
        payload.chat_text = tmsg; // It's michael29's turn
        payload.user_id = playerNames[pp];
        payload.game_no = game_no;
        socket.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
    }
});
```

---

```
// socket gets oppo's response
function checkJson(res, sttr_id, game_no) {
    if(res.action=="game_move"){
        // find player
        var pp=playerNames.indexOf(res.user_id);
        cpos=res.cardno;
        playCard_oppo(pp, cpos);
    }
}
```

---

```
// turn an oppo's card face up and update scores
function playCard_oppo(pp, cardno) {
    //  and move it to the stack
    topoc= parseInt($("#oppo_card" + cardno).css('top'));
    leftoc=parseInt($("#oppo_card" + cardno).css('left'));
    $("#oppo_card" + cardno).css({ top: topoc, left: leftoc, opacity: "50%" });
    .
    .
    if (joiner=="") {
        // tell oppoPlays fn that the card has moved 
    }
}
```

The game is similar to uno in concept but with a scoring component

(aimed to help children with basic arithmetic).

Comment: There is evidence on the code of messaging between players but not of centralised game state. You need to start thinking of this as a star configuration of players connected to a central server.

Comment: Centralised game state is effected by the game starter being the central controller. Whether this client or the server waits while a player moves, synchronicity is still the problem.

Comment: "upto" or "up to" Grammatically speaking, we know "upto" is incorrect when a part of a sentence. Yet, when used as an operative on a numerical ( upto 50% discount on woolens... ) it appears to have complete acceptance. https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/137090-quot-upto-quot-or-quot-up-to-quot

Comment: Think of game starter as nothing more than a player with extra privileges. And yes, synchronisation is all important.

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect you are correct but centralising the game on the server will require a hefty re-write of much of the code. I must first exhaust all other possibilities. I wish I understood promise and Q and yield better. Also my server "expertise" is php and I'm not confident in php's ability to handle many game instances.

Comment: Although it is unconventional, I suppose there's nothing to stop you having the game centralised on the Starter's machine with an actual server acting as a conduit for messages/commands/requests/state. But it would still be *conceptually* a star system.

Comment: Yes, put the complete rewrite on hold.

Comment: It is absolutely a star system as far as human players are concerned. Bear in mind that game starter can elect to play only AI opponents. In this scenario it becomes purely a round-robin implementation. With human players it tries to become a hybrid of the two concepts, and this is obviously where I'm hitting my difficulty.

Comment: I'm starting to think something along these lines:- `while (oppoType[pp] == "AI") { AI play; pp++; }` `humanTurn()` contains suitable _callback_ or _promise_, etc.

Comment: Too much for a comment, I'll post an answer ...

Answer (score 1):

Consider having a board state that is a global and player/AI moves modify it. Then, when it is time for the AI opponent to make a move, it consults the current board state and decides the move.

If your board state is just represented by elements on the page you'll need a way to scan it and calculate a useful in-memory representation of the board state. Without details of your implementation it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: I have updated the question to explain that the game is similar to uno. There is a deck of 54 cards, 7 cards distributed to each player and one turned up for all to see. If you wish to try the game you can visit testlr03.2learnisfun.com, user guest, pw ok and select game chris on the game feed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start thinking in terms of a play-cycle, something like this :

1. (host) Broadcasts game state.
2. (host) Awaits confirmation from all clients that broadcast was received.
3. (clients) Render game state.
4. (host) Receives confirmations then informs next client (and hence its player) that it is his/her/its turn.
5. (host) Awaits player's move
6. (client) Unlocks UI allowing player to make move.
7. (player) Makes move.
8. (client) Sends move command and re-locks UI.
9. (host) Receives move command and modifies game state accordingly.

Then back to 1.

Also, think of AI players as just a special case of human players. If you can get it right for humans, then (re)introducing AI should be fairly simple.

Comment: The game state is sent to all human players once the game has a full complement of players and starts. Thereafter each human is told that player _pp_ moved card _cardno_ from which info they emulate the move and update the local score. The critical point is 5. await player's move. How to do this without blocking the game starter's thread is the question. Of interest, also note, that humans can chat through the 'chatWindow' at any time, either directly or broadcast. This facility allows for skills transfer amongst team members.

Comment: "How to do this without blocking ..." ... that's where promises come into play.

Comment: Even a promise doesn't help; what's required is the creation of an event (say "humanPlayed") that gets triggered at the end of updating cards and scores etc. and gets turned off again. My problem is to construct an un-automatic loop, if I can call it that, so that the game starter's thread doesn't automtically get on with the next player.

Comment: You might need to do what is called "long polling".

Comment: I think I have solved the problem by creating a window event "humanPlayed" and triggering it when the human has actually played. I had to separate the human play logic from the AI play logic. Once I'd done this, it was a lot easier to see a solution. It's a bit buggy at the moment but once I'm completely comfortable with it I will answer my own question, in detail, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The solution hinged around two things:-

1. separating the AI player code from the human player code;
2. adding and removing a window event that's triggered after a human's move is detected.

The condensed code now looks like this:-

```
// if this is game starter give each player a turn
if (joiner == "") {
    //  there's always at least one
    pp = 1;
    if (oppoType[pp] == "AI") { AIplays(); } else { humanPlays(); }
}

function humanPlays () {
    // tell human player that it's their turn
    var yourTurnmsg="It's "+playerNames[pp]+"'s turn"
    $("#text_message").val(yourTurnmsg).trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { keyCode: 13, which: 13 }));

    //window.addEventListener("humanPlayed", function(evnt) {
    $(window).on("humanPlayed", function(evnt) {
        endOfTurn();
    });
}

function endOfTurn () {
    if (!(winner)) {
        if (pp++ != numberofplayers) {
            if (oppoType[pp] == "AI") {
                setTimeout(function (){ $("#clickForNextPlayer").show(); }, 1000);
            } else {
                $("#clickForNextPlayer").trigger('click');
            }
        }
    }
}

// click for next player
$("#clickForNextPlayer").on('click', function() {
    $("#clickForNextPlayer").hide();
    $(window).off("humanPlayed");
    if (pp == numberofplayers) {
        // uncover outStack for game starter to play
        $("#outStackcover").hide();
        return;
    }
    if (oppoType[pp] == "AI") { AIplays(); } else { humanPlays(); }
});

function AIplays () {
    AIcardno = chooseCard(pp, diffLevel);
    .
    .
    if ($("#chatWindow").is(":visible")) {
        payload = new Object();
        payload.action="game_move";
        payload.game_no=gamestarted;
        payload.user_id=playerNames[pp];
        payload.cardno=AIcardno;
        socket.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
    }
    $("#oppo_card" + cc).css('background-image', "url(JerseyTeam" + playerNumbers[(pp == numberofplayers ? 1 : pp)] + ".gif)");
    outStackturn();
    endOfTurn();
}
```